# Each word in a title on their own line HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some dynamic titles where the design requires each word to be on their own line. Here is the desired look:
http://jsfiddle.net/alanweibel/2LEmF/2/ (note the black backgrounds for each word)

The problem I need help with is keeping the style above while having the whole title inside of one tag. I cannot dynamically insert H1's before and after each word.

I need to change the HTML markup from

```html
<div class="tagline">
<h1>
    Oh
</h1>
<h1>
    Look
</h1>
<h1>
    A
</h1>
<h1>
    Headline
</h1>
<h1>
    Thanks
</h1>
</div>
```

to something similar to

```html
<div class="tagline">
    <h1>
        Oh Look A Headline Thanks
    </h1>
</div>
```

while keeping the same style as in the link above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HksP2/

It looks perfect in IE9, IE8 and recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera; all on Windows 7. It degrades reasonably well in IE7. In Safari on Mac, it's *almost* perfect.

This is based off a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105650/span-background-color-padding-problems/7106125#7106125). Quoting myself from that answer:

> Note that the `line-height` and `padding` adjustments can be *very
>   tricky* to get right.

`line-height: 1.83;` looks good, and was found by picking something that looked close to what you wanted, then using trial and error to find something that works in both Chrome and Firefox (they render text differently).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tagline">
    <h1><span>
        Oh Look A Headline Thanks
    </span></h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tagline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    line-height: 1.83; 
    padding: 1px 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
}
.tagline h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tagline span { 
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your only option for doing this, that I'm aware of, is to write some javascript that will take your `<h1>oh look ..</h1>` stuff and split it out into separate h1 tags.

---

**update:**

I just thought of a way: http://jsfiddle.net/2LEmF/10/

Basically, you need to move your background color up to the main div.  Then set the width on your h1 to something that is going to force the text to break along normal text breaking rules.  Something like 10px.

I'm not sure what this is going to do on a number of browsers as you are essentially giving a size that is way to small to your H1... but it might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that. I'll see if anyone else has a solution before I go that route though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the background to be the same width as each word as in the original example.

Comment: @AlanWeibel: That isn't possible without JS. +1 for a JS solution.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are back to javascript then.

Comment: @Blender: It's possible as shown in my answer, though it's not as robust as one would hope.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of how to get one line per word:

https://jsfiddle.net/xaq5ttf2/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tagline">
    <h1>
        Oh Look A Headline Thanks
    </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tagline h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of the `h1` to less than that of the smallest word e.g. 10px.

It produces exactly the same result as your example (at least on Chrome and Firefox).

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/W2Ruk/).

Comment: Thanks but this solution does fake a line-break, but it does not keep the background styles as in the example.

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but I've managed to shoehorn a background in using the `:before` pseudo element. you can see the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TttLX/).

Answer (score 0):

You could search and replace spaces with `<br />` to get this look:

http://jsfiddle.net/WwbUL/

Comment: This solution does not solve my problem. It's the same as the example but with <br /> after each word instead of <h1> tags.I need the final output to look like it is in the example link, but I cannot insert any html tags before and after each word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.  It seems that you're stuck with the HTML as posted in your question, but you want it to display in-line?

What about just adding `display:inline;` to .tagline ?

http://jsfiddle.net/XmCLd/

Or is it the other way around?  That you have normal-looking HTML, but you need to split your lines at the spaces?

http://jsfiddle.net/GQ44u/

Comment: I need the final output to look like it is in the example link, but I cannot insert any html tags before and after each word.

Comment: Thanks but this solution does fake a line-break, but it does not keep the background styles as in the example.

Comment: I didn't feel inclined to clone your styles; if the faking works, you can write your own styles.  That way, the person doing the work knows *precisely* what you want.

Comment: The whole point of this issue revolves around the styles. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `tagline` div really thin and make it `block` instead of `inline`. Then make the h1 `inline`.

```
.tagline
{
    width: 1px;
    margin:5px;
    display: block;
}
.tagline h1
{
    color:#fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display: inline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmCLd/3/) here.

Comment: Thanks but this solution does fake a line-break, but it does not keep the background styles as in the example. Your solution does not keep the desired padding.