# Create a background color on a breaking inline element

Tags: html, css, background-color

In a website I'm coding, the designer wishes to have ragged-right text with a background color (over a photo). The design prescribes some padding on both the left and the right side and also a well balanced background: all background "blocks" have the same height and stack tightly on top of each other. The following image shows an example.

[image: example of properly padded, ragged-right text with a solic background-color]

Searching for solutions for this, it turned out that this design has two distinct challenges:

1. Make sure that any left and right padding are applied to *all* lines; and
2. Make sure that the vertical spacing is *perfect*.

Challenge 1 can be solved using some [css-tricks on multi-line-padded-text](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/). This has also been discussed here on SO on several Q&A's: [span background-color & padding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105650/2286722), [CSS create padding before line-break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6099857/2286722), to link some.

Challenge 2 is a bit trickier and is also related to the `box-shadow`-solution for the left and right padding on all lines.

First on this last point: even after carefully setting top and bottom padding to the text, I notice subtle errors (in Firefox, which is definitely one of the targeted browsers):

[image: subtle errors (in Firefox) on the box-shadow]

These subtle lines may also occur between (some of) the lines upon zooming. This would be indicative of a non-exact line-height (thus padding). However, setting the vertical padding too much (to be on the safe side) also has problems:

[image]

I used a semi-transparent background (and box-shadow) here to highlight the issues. First, the solution will not work for cases where transparency is needed. And second: the background "blocks" are not anymore of equal height (e.g. the gap between lines 2 and 4 is much narrower than line 4).

It turns out that there exists an inherent problem with setting the right padding: it cannot be predicted exactly how high the actual `line-height` is (i.e. not without digging *very* deep into the internals of the font metrics). Especially in cases where the font used is not predictable (which is common on the web).

---

So the question is, how to add a background-color to a flowing piece of text, having it properly left and right padded, and having the lines to stack exactly on top of each other?

Some caveats:

- Setting `display: inline-block` is a no-no: it will create a rectangular background.
- The afore-mentioned solutions work "a bit", which is not enough. They have their issues, as illustrated.
- Obviously, I am looking for a css-only solution, NOT javascript.
- Of course, the text used is server-generated and can change.

I have found one solution which works for me: using a background *image* of the right color, which can be scaled to *exactly* one line-height. I will submit this self-answer. Although I do like the hack, I am still open for other suggestions.

Comment: [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html) is also a deep level post on why the height of the content box is unpredictable. `line-height` can be set in css, but not `content-area-height` or `leading` (or `half-leading`). Background is drawn on the content-area, not the line-height.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</span>
    <span>Sed ultrices, leo eu porta mattis ...</span>
</p>
```

```css
p {
    width: 30em; /* as needed */
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
}
span {
    padding: 0.6em 0.5em;
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIABAFVVVf///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=);
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -ms-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 1px 2em ;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Notice that I did not specify a `font-family`: font metrics are now not an issue anymore. Also, any `font-size` can be used. It is important to match the `line-height` to the settings for the `span` (see below), but this is also 'free'. It's even possible to use line heights lower than `normal`, although ascenders and descenders may of course extend from the background in that case.

The actual trick is specifying a background image and setting its height *exactly* equal to the line height (`2em` in this example). For this, I use a single-pixel gif image that I crafted in the Gimp. The string in the [data-uri](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) is just the base-64 encoded content of the gif file (of 35 bytes). This gif is then expanded to the desired height using `background-size` and setting `background-repeat: repeat-x` makes sure that the width is set properly. Not setting vertical repeating allows us to set *an imprecise amount of vertical padding* (see below). `background-position: center` takes care of properly aligning the text to the background vertically.

The vertical padding is another part of the trick: set it high enough so that the padding (both top and bottom) plus the line-box height exceed the line height. `0.5em` should have been enough, but I'm using `0.6em` here to be on the safe side (and it distinguishes nicely from the `0.5em` horizontal value). Since there is *no background-color*, everything outside the background-image is transparent! (if the span inherits some background-color, just override it to be `transparent`)

The horizontal padding (`0.5em` here), together with the `box-decoration-break: clone` setting (also with prefixes, although I do not know which are actually needed) takes care of the left and right padding, also setting it equal for all lines.

For semi-transparent backgrounds, a dito png-image will work instead of the gif. I chose a gif here because of the file size. The image can also be loaded separately, but using the data-uri saves a http-request (which would be way more than the current 70 bytes and take a long time).