# First word selector for every <p> within a <div>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have referenced the following Q&A: [First word selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458605/jquery-first-word-selector)

I am looking to use the same sort of `<span></span>` setup, however, I would like for it to occur for every first word of every `<p>` within a particular `<div>`. How can I specify this?

```
    $(window).load(function(){
(function () { 
    var node = $("p").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
        text = node.text(),
        first = text.slice(0,text.indexOf(" "));

    if (!node.length)
        return;

    node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
    node.before('<span>' + first + '</span>');
})();
  });
```

Within the stylesheet, I then can take the simple `<span></span>` that's been applied to various selectors, and specify what the 'span' function will do with each selector.

Comment: Not an answer, but FYI CSS has [first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line) and [first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) selectors

Comment: Yes, I am working with first word, which isn't a pseudo-element.

Comment: yep, I know. Just thought it might come in handy. :)

Comment: @Michael Cornett could you mark dakdad as answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

dakdad has a much better solution: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHa5T/3/)

@Michael Cornett: could you mark dakdad as answer please? :)

Answer (score 2):

@Joseph re: fiddle example
Wouldn't replace be easier?

```js
$("#target p").each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/^([^\s]+)\s?/, '<span>$1</span> '));
});
```

Comment: Yes... yes that would be much *much* better :P Thank you much, dakdad.

Comment: @Joseph the only downside is that the bound events are lost - unless they are live events of course as explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458605/first-word-selector)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("p").each(function(){

    var text = $(this).text() + " ";
    var newMarkup =
      "<span class='firstWord'>" + 
      text.substr(0,text.indexOf(" ")) +
      "</span>" + 
      text.substr(text.indexOf(" "));
    $(this).html(newMarkup);
});
  });
```

Here is a link to a sample of what I'm working with: http://www.meestro.com/vespers