# Using JS Lettering not working with output text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, letteringjs

I'm trying to use the letter tool I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865714/highlight-an-individual-word-within-a-text-block-on-hover) tutorial to highlight text.

If I put text between the `spans` initially, it will work:

`<span class="npc_dialog_dictionary_chinese">this will work...</span>`

If I put my mouse over "this will work" text in between the spans, it works fine...

---

But I want to apply that to text that will be generated when `$('.npc_dialog_dictionary_chinese').html(dialog_text);` updates the `span` with the javascript variable `dialog_text`.

So let's say `dialog_text` is updated with "some text" when I press a key... and then the jquery `html()` function above updates the `span`... it is that generated text I'd like to be highlighted.

How can I get that to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you would have to reinitialize .lettering() on that text block.

Comment: Duh... Not sure why I didn't think of that. It works now lol. Thanks!