# wordpress widget title add span

Tags: wordpress, title

I want to make the first word of a widget title a different color.

The widget code is this:

```
'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
```

How can I had a span or a class in there so I can specify a different color in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do this by just modifying widget code. If you really need first word highlighted, you may look for some javascript, jquery solution like here: [First word selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458605/first-word-selector)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by just modifying widget code. Find in your theme the file `functions.php`. Next, find the lines:

```
'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
'after_title'   => '</h3>',
```

and change them to

```
'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title"><span>',
'after_title'   => '</span></h3>',
```

Add lines your style.css

```
h3.widget-title span {
background-color: #27b56b;
padding: 2px 9px 2px 8px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
}
```