# How to place a <span> on 1st word within a H1 and href tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert a span around the first word in an H1 tag.

Unfortunately the tags can also be links and can include classes etc, eg:

1. Source = `<h1>This is a test</h1>`

   Output = `<h1><span>This</span> is a test</h1>`
2. Source = `<h1 class="blah blah"><a href="#">This is a test<a/></h1>`

   Output = `<h1 class="blah blah"><a href="#"><span>This</span> is a test<a/></h1>`

Has anyone done this before in say jQuery?

Comment: this link might helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458605/first-word-selector

Comment: check my answer and I saw the problem with HTML correct it <h1 class="blah blah"><a href="#">This is a test</a></h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for both "a" tag in it and plain text.

```
$('h1').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('a').length>0)
        {
            var text = $(this).find('a').html();
            text = text.split(' ');
            if(text.length>0)
            {
                text[0] = '<span>' + text[0] + '</span>';
                $(this).find('a').html(text.join(' '));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var text = $(this).html();
            text = text.split(' ');
            if(text.length>0)
            {
                text[0] = '<span>' + text[0] + '</span>';
                $(this).html(text.join(' '));
            }
        }
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vUneZ/5/)

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by

```
$(' your selecter').each(function(){
     var one = $(this);
     one.html(one.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span>data</span>'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/)   you can have it wrap words and letters. Its awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It will work for both example.

```
$('h1').each(function(){
     var self = $(this);
     var p = self.text().split(' ');
     var html = self.html().replace(p[0], '<span>'+ p[0] +'</span>');
     self.html(html);
});
```

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6seeW/)**