# Jquery: first word color span issue for link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with first word when is as link, word appears not normal.

```
     $('h3')
  .each(function () {
    var h = $(this).html();
    var index = h.indexOf(' ');
    if (index == -1) {
        index = h.length;
    }
    $(this).html('<span style="color:#fff;">' + h.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + h.substring(index, h.length));
});
```

[image: problem behaviour]

And when not appear the link in the h3 tag looks good

[image: nice behaviour]

Comment: `.html()` returns what is within the HTML you selected. So it will also display your tags if there are any and all of your text. Tip: if you provide HTML people are more likely to help you and understand the problem better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to style everything inside h3 besides links? Maybe you should use CSS for that :)

Comment: It would help if you showed some sample html, but are you saying you want some jquery code that styles whatever the first word is in all h3 elements, regardless of whether or not the first word happens to be contained in a child element such as an anchor? (Where your current attempt is going wrong because it works by finding the first space, which works out to be inside the attributes of the `<a>` tag.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use color in span element to set color in a tag. You need to set the color in a tag itself:

```js
$('h3').each(function () {
    if($(this).contents().first().is('a')){
        $(this).contents().first().css('color','#fff');
    }else {
        var node = $(this).contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).first();
        var text = node.text();
        var first = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(" "));
        node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
        node.before('<span style="color:#fff">' + first + '</span>');
    }
});
```

```css
h3{
  background: #f00;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><a>test</a> word</h3>
<h3>test word</h3>
```

Code for first word selector taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458605/first-word-selector).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/jnmwyagy/2/

```
<h3><a href="#">google</a><p><span class="text">First</span> Word</p></h3>
<h3><a href="#">google</a><p><span class="text">First</span> Word</p></h3>
```

jQuery

```
 $('h3')
     .each(function () {
     $(this).find('.text').css("color", "red");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for opening `a` tags, not for spaces.

```
$('h3').each(function () {
    var h = $(this).html();
    var index = h.indexOf('<a');
    if (index == -1) {
        index = h.length;
    }
    $(this).html('<span style="color:#fff;">' + h.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + h.substring(index, h.length));
});
```

**And seriously, it would be better just to apply CSS styles for `h3` and `a` tags.**