# Bold First Word In Dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Ok so I have this drop down and I want to bold the first word in the main level of the nav..*See which ones in my code below with comments.*

To make it clear I would like the words **Our**, **Lorem**, and **Another** to be wrapped in a `strong` tag or a `span` tag since they are the first words in the main level of the navigation. How can I accomplish this **with jQuery**?

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="topnav">
  <li class="mainNavFirst"><a href="/">Our Home</a></li> <!-- bold this 'our' -->
  <li class="mainNavMiddle"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a><!-- bold this 'Lorem' -->
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class="sectionTitle">
          <h2><a href="#">Ipsum Lorem</a></h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Just a random link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Just a random link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="sectionTitle">
          <h2><a href="#">Ipsum Lorem</a></h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mainNavLast"><a href="#">Another Link</a></li><!-- bold this 'Another' -->
</ul>
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-increase-size-of-first-word

Comment: `<strong>` doesn't work in `<a>` apparently, but please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/ckWks/1/.

Comment: hmm. strange. is there a way that I can say the first word of the nav li to have font-weight:bold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#topnav > li > a').html(function(i,html){
    return html.replace(/^\s*([^\s]+)(\s|$)/, '<span>$1 </span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LKXKs/3/

---

**EDIT:** Fixed it so it will still work if there's only one word in the `<a>`, or if there are leading spaces.

Comment: I like this because its short and minimal however homepage doesn't get wrapped in a span tag.

Comment: @SirB: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean "Our Home"? Only "Our" Should be wrapped, right?

Comment: @SirB: You're welcome. Must have been one of the whitespace issues. :o)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(function(){
      $('#topnav > li > a').each(function(item, index){
            var firstWord = $(this).text().split(" ")[0];
            var newText = $(this).text().replace(firstWord, "<span>"+firstWord +"</span>");
            $(this).html(newText);
      });
    });
```

Then use CSS style:

```
#topnav > li > a span { font-weight: 800; }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zbfcS/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good method, based on @jensgram's answer at [First Word in String with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760085/first-word-in-string-with-jquery):

```
<script>
    boldFirstWord($(".clearfix .mainNavFirst > a"));
    boldFirstWord($(".clearfix .mainNavMiddle > a"));
    boldFirstWord($(".clearfix .mainNavLast > a"));

    function boldFirstWord(element) {
        element.html( element.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<strong>$1</strong>'));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you dynamically loading the `nav` or will it change frequently?  If not, you probably do not need any extra scripting added to your page re changing the first word with `js`.  Just add the `strong` tags to the appropriate word.

Comment: Yes the nav is dynamically being generated.