# jQuery Wrapping some string with conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have string need to be wrapped by tag `HTML` with conditional like this:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Then nothing will happen

```
<h1>Test Lagi</h1>
```

Then the first word will be wrapped by `span`, result `<h1><span>Test</span> Lagi</h1>`

```
<h1>Test Lagi ah</h1>
```

Then only the first word will be wrapper by `span`, result:

```
<h1><span>Test</span> Lagi ah</h1>
```

How to do that in jQuery?

Comment: Please don't use signatures. Also, there may be a somewhat related question and solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760085/first-word-in-string-with-jquery

Comment: it's wrong to saying thank you @_@

Comment: @JIP, I'm not against a "thank you" as a sign off, just pointing out that the OP also included a signature, which the FAQ frowns upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following CoryLarson's link Here is a better solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/avmFe/

```
$(function(){
    $('h1').each(function(){
       var me = $(this);
        if(/(\W+)/.test(me.html())) {
          me.html(me.html().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('h1').each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var wordArray = txt.split(' ');

        var new_first = '<span>'+wordArray[0]+'</span>';
        var new_txt = txt .replace("wordArray[0]",new_first);
        $(this).html(new_txt);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Rs4TA/1/

```
$('*:contains("Test")').html('<span>Test</span>');
```

If your "test" is a static text, it could be done by this way.

Comment: word `test` is not static word.

Answer (score -1):

This does it: http://jsfiddle.net/RE9rp/1/

And here's the JS:

```
function wrapFirstWord($el, word){
    $el.each(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var wordArray = txt.split(' ');
        if(wordArray[0] === word && wordArray.length > 1){
            var newHTML = '<span>' + word + '</span>';
            for(var i = 1; i < wordArray.length; i++){
                newHTML += ' ' + wordArray[i];
            }
            $(this).html(newHTML);
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    wrapFirstWord($('h1'),'Test');
});
```

You simply pass to `wrapFirstWord()` the set of elements you want to check for the word ($el), as well as the word you are looking for.

Comment: im sorry, i mean word test is only for testing purpose not the real implementation. The first word can be `test`, `morning`, `afternoon`

Comment: Does that mean that you want something that will wrap any first word? Or you want to be able to pass the chosen word to the function as an argument?

Comment: i want something that wrap the first word

Comment: See my updated fiddle/code. This will let you accomplish the task with any word and for any element.